# what is [^\\d] ? how replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""); is working?

Tags: java

I want to remove alphabets from my string, I used replace function as follows

```
String hello = "hello007";
hello = hello.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

It worked, but I do know how it’s working? What is “^” and “//d”? 
I get to know ^ is “xor”. But unable to understand usage?

Why are we covering it under []? Please guide me?

Answer (score 5):

The expression [^\\d] means not a digit where

```
[] means one of these..
[^ ..] means (not one of these)
\  is escape character (because in Java you need to escape it)
\d   means digit
```

SO if you check an online checker, you're looking for \d, which means all digits, which is the same as

```
[^0-9]
```

So it will match 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', and replace each one with a blank ("")

Comment: Thanks, I'm half way to fully understand . 

why did we used escape character? what are we trying to escape here?

Comment: if you put in \d then java will thing it's some special character.  Just like \n is special.

Answer (score 2):

- `[...]` matches any single character in brackets
- `^` matches beginning of line
- `[^...]` matches any single character not in brackets
- `\d` matches digits (equivalent to [0-9])

Answer (score 2):

Whatever inside the [...] is a regular expression.

This link http://regexone.com/ will be useful to learn about regular expression.

How hello = hello.replaceAll("[^\d]", ""); works is , in the value stored by hello, every character is replaced by an empty character and is again stored in hello.

Answer (score 1):

You are using regular expressions. What you are saying is "Replace every [Not a digit] with nothing".

Here is more about regexp in Java:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html